# Node.js mssql return query result to ajax

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to learning Node.js, so I'm still getting used to asynchronous programming and callbacks. I'm trying to insert a record into a MS SQL Server database and return the new row's ID to my view.

The mssql query is working correctly when printed to console.log. My problem is not knowing how to properly return the data.

Here is my mssql query - in addJob.js:

```
var config = require('../../db/config');

async function addJob(title) {

    var sql = require('mssql');
    const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
    var conn = pool;

    let sqlResult = '';
    let jobID = '';
    conn.connect().then(function () {
        var req = new sql.Request(conn);

        req.query(`INSERT INTO Jobs (Title, ActiveJD) VALUES ('${title}', 0) ; SELECT @@IDENTITY AS JobID`).then(function (result) {

            jobID = result['recordset'][0]['JobID'];

            conn.close();

            //This prints the correct value
            console.log('jobID: ' + jobID);

        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Unable to add job: ' + err);
            conn.close();
        });

    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to SQL: ' + err);
    });


   // This prints a blank
   console.log('jobID second test: ' + jobID)
   return jobID;
}

module.exports = addJob;
```

This is my front end where a modal box is taking in a string and passing it to the above query.  I want it to then receive the query's returned value and redirect to another page.

```
// ADD NEW JOB
            $("#navButton_new").on(ace.click_event, function() {
                bootbox.prompt("New Job Title", function(result) {
                    if (result != null) {

                        var job = {};
                        job.title = result;

                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: JSON.stringify(job),
                            contentType: 'application/json',
                            url: 'jds/addJob',                      
                            success: function(data) {

                                // this just prints that data is an object. Is that because I'm returning a promise? How would I unpack that here?
                                console.log('in success:' + data);

                                // I want to use the returned value here for a page redirect
                                //window.location.href = "jds/edit/?jobID=" + data;
                                return false;
                            },
                            error: function(err){
                                console.log('Unable to add job: ' + err);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {

                    }
                });
            });
```

And finally here is the express router code calling the function:

```
const express = require('express');
//....
const app = express();
//....

app.post('/jds/addJob', function(req, res){

    let dataJSON = JSON.stringify(req.body)
    let parsedData = JSON.parse(dataJSON);

    const addJob = require("../models/jds/addJob");
    let statusResult = addJob(parsedData.title);

    statusResult.then(result => {
        res.send(req.body);
    });  
});
```

I've been reading up on promises and trying to figure out what needs to change here, but I'm having no luck.  Can anyone provide any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually return a value from your function for things to work. Due to having nested Promises you need a couple returns here. One of the core features of promises is if you return a Promise it participates in the calling Promise chain.

So change the following lines

```
jobID = result['recordset'][0]['JobID'];
```

to

```
return result['recordset'][0]['JobID']
```

and

```
req.query(`INSERT INTO Jobs (Title, ActiveJD) VALUES ('${title}', 0) ; SELECT @@IDENTITY AS JobID`).then(function (result) {
```

to

```
return req.query(`INSERT INTO Jobs (Title, ActiveJD) VALUES ('${title}', 0) ; SELECT @@IDENTITY AS JobID`).then(function (result) {
```

and

```
conn.connect().then(function () {
```

to

```
return conn.connect().then(function () {
```

You may need to move code around that is now after the return.  You would also be well served moving `conn.close()` into a single `.finally` on the end of the connect chain.

I recommend writing a test that you can use to play around with things until you get it right.

```
const jobId = await addJob(...)
console.log(jobId)
```

Alternatively rewrite the code to use await instead of .then() calls.